# Best application monitoring system with dashboard

Tags: performance, charts, monitoring, dashboard, graphite

I have been playing with Graphite as application monitoring system but I'm wondering if there's something better out there for what I want.

Here are a few requirements I have in mind:

1. Dashboards (easy to create/change)
2. the items on the dashboard should be mostly charts but also colored "number boxes" (a la http://shopify.github.io/dashing/)
3. when a metrics goes below/beyond a certain value show some warnings on the screen (different frame/background) and potentially send an email
4. setting up a rule-to-warn (see above) should be simple to do and have many ways to specify a threshold (absolute value, +/- the min/max/avg over the past 30 days, percentile, etc...)
5. Clicking on one of the charts/boxes would redirect to a larger/more detailed chart or a "sub-dashboard"

I would prefer open-source but I'm open to commercial products especially cloud-based solutions.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use the following combination:

- Dashboard: [Grafana](http://grafana.org/). It is really good looking and makes easy to create and edit dashboards. Unfortunately it doesn't have colored "number boxes" but you can also look into using a wider-purpose one like Geckoboard or Ducksboard for this end.
- Alerting system: [Seyren](https://github.com/scobal/seyren/). Lets you specify alerts when any metric trespasses a certain threshold and alerts via mail and dozen of other ways, readily integrated. However it doesn't ease in any way dealing with historical values, percentiles, etc. You have to do this manually via Graphite functions. Another popular option: [Cabot](http://cabotapp.com/). I use Seyren instead because it looks more active and is lighter to deploy.

Unfortunately there is not final "answer" to your question, only suggestions. You might find more appropriate forums for your question than Stackoverflow, like mailing lists or Reddit.

Hope it helps anyhow! :)

Comment: checking out grafana - looks promising

Answer (score 2):

Your question states prefer open source, but if you’re really open to commercial option, I think the  ZingChart JavaScript charting library meets your requirements.

**1. Dashboards (easy to create/change)**: ZingChart uses a CSS-like syntax that is pretty easy to use and edit.

**2. Dashboard items should be charts and number boxes**: The library allows you to create widgets to display items like you've described. Here is a demo with number boxes -- http://www.zingchart.com/playground/presentation/51b21c1a3c8ae

**3 . Warnings on screen**: As you can see the in the demo above, rules have been set for the number boxes to display in green for increases and red for decreases. Similar rules can be set for a range of values. (Which addresses number 4).

You could even use multiple rules sets for a values that are close to reaching the threshold. http://zingchart.com/playground/run/5460f51991002 This example shows rules set to place a red marker on data points below the value of 200.

**4 . Rule-to-warn**: There are a variety of ways to use [rules](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/rules/) to replicate your desired warning. You can also combine rules with our [API](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/api-events/) and create warnings as well as fire an event which can be used to trigger an email.

Its not mentioned in your question but if real time data is a consideration, ZingChart also provides the ability to transfer data via http or websocket protocols.  I’m on the team at ZingChart so if you have any questions about the demo or the features described, please feel free to reach out.

Comment: Thanks Merrily. I'm actually a satisfied ZingChart user. I'm seriously considering ZingChart for the charting part but I don't think it will cut it for the other requirements.

Comment: Jerome, I took the liberty of sharing your response to the team so they could reach out to you personally to evaluate your needs.

Comment: No problem, Merrily. I got their email but I'm out of the office today. I'll respond tomorrow. Good follow-up!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the right budget the best tool is splunk. It is not cloud based but it is the best when it comes to analyzing data and creating graphs and dashboards out of generated data by scripts and log files.

Splunk comes with a very flexible query language and the ability to create scheduled searches that can be used as a very robust monitoring solution. I still did not find any better product but the downside is the high price.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'll check it out.